# VBA code to select a cell when specific letters appears and sort

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help to understand and modify some code I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19723412/835002):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nextRow As Long
    For Each cell In Range("K50:K200")
        If StrComp(cell, "Late", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            nextRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Range("J" & nextRow) = Range("B" & cell.Row)
            Range("K" & nextRow) = Range("C" & cell.Row)
            Range("N" & nextRow) = Range("G" & cell.Row)
            Range("O" & nextRow) = Range("H" & cell.Row)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

What I'd like is:

- If `late` is along with some other words, say `late submit`, copy values in `B` and paste in `J`
- if row `K` has `progress` along with say `in progress`, copy values in `C` to `K`
- If `sick` is with say `on sick leave`, copy values in `G` to `N`

I tried so hard,  but I still didn't succeed in modifying this code to suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

> If late is along with some other words, say late submit

In that case, instead of `StrComp`, use `Instr`

```
If Instr(1, cell, "Late", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

Similarly for the rest.

If you check Excel's help you will notice that Instr returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string **within** another.

**Syntax**

*InStr([start, ]string1, string2[, compare])*